# Create a Macro repeatable for newly downloaded worksheets of the same format

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a Macro that will be used on multiple worksheets that all will have the same exact format. In theory, someone will download one of these worksheets and be able to use the macro to format data. Is there a way to be able to have the macro run in the newly downloaded worksheet without having to open the original worksheet where the macro was created? The macro is intended for other computers to be able to use.

The macro itself is very simple. Simply entering values/trim formulas with some formatting.

```
  Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ...continues
```

Comment: I believe you can do this from an addin, where it executes upon opening a file.  You would need to have some check to see if the macro will run, e.g., *if cells(1,1)="BLAH" then*.  That's a least an option.  This would be client specific, so each computer would need to have the macro.

Comment: Is there any way to not have it be client specific? I need it to be able to be used by other employees

Comment: My understanding is that any instance of Excel would need to agree to to run a macro, as this is a security measure.  You wouldn't be able to have them download a file and have it just run a macro/addin without going into the computer specific Excel and turning off macro security settings.

Comment: You can have each person modify their trust center settings in order to avoid having them OK enabling macros, but if you are going to that step you may as well have them install an add-in.